# Javascript "Unexpected identifier" in chrome web console

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover, onmouseover

I am using some javascript code to reveal an image when a div is moused over:

```
function show()
{
document.getElementById("reveal").innerHTML = "<img src=\"..." border=\"0\">";
}

function hide()
{
document.getElementById("reveal").innerHTML = "Hidden";
}
```

Then the HTML:

```
<a onMouseOver="show()" onMouseOut="hide();"><div id="reveal">Mouseover me!</div></a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you forget to escape a quote after the ... part, or is that just a result of sanitizing the code before posting?

Comment: And Java != Javascript. This should be remembered by all beginners :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax highlighting gives it away. You missed a `\` before the `"` which comes before `border`.

```
document.getElementById("reveal").innerHTML = "<img src=\"...\" border=\"0\">";
```

Alternately, use single quotes to delimit your JS strings:

```
document.getElementById('reveal').innerHTML = '<img src="..." border="0">';
```

No escaping needed when you properly mix single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a backslash here

```
document.getElementById("reveal").innerHTML = "<img src=\"...\" border=\"0\">";
```

(at the end of src)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead in the show function...

```
document.getElementById("reveal").innerHTML = '<img src="..." border="0">';
```

instead of escaping, just use single quotes